# Is there any way to implement password expiry in Amazon Cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have to implement the password expiry policy in Amazon cognito. I have checked the documents but didn't find any solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately AWS doesn't have any built in password expiration for congnito. You can however have your own implementation by creating a new custom field that tracks the timestamp when password was created/changed. You can then use [AdminResetUserPassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminResetUserPassword.html) when the timestamp is too old. You can have a lambda query all users and check this parameter daily. Update the timestamp and reset the password if it is too old.